# Can not parse the date field

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, dateparser

I have been trying to fix this issue but could not find a solution to it.

I have a date column as string type . Trying to convert it to timestamp using date_parse but getting the following error.

> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2021-09-28
> 21:05:28.272159" is malformed at "21:05:28.272159"

my query is

```
"date_parse"(a.commitdatetime, '%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s.%f') commitdatetime
```

do you have any ideas  how to fix this issue? Thanks for your time from now

Comment: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions - See the `Specifier`s, the casing is important example (h and H mean 2 different things as do Y and y).

Comment: `parse_datetime` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [format strings documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions). `%y` and `%h` should be substituted with `%Y` and `%H` correspondingly:

```sql
select date_parse('2021-09-28 21:05:28.272159', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2021-09-28 21:05:28.272 |